# Btest function in fortran, is there any equivalent in python?

Tags: python, fortran

I would like to use the equivalent of the [`btest`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/BTEST.html) function in Fortran  in Python. Do you know if there's something I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like:

```
def btest(i, pos):
    return i & (1 << pos)
```

Comment: You may prefer to cast the result to `bool`.

Comment: Like this: `bool(i & (1 << pos))`